# Matrix Algebra method for calculating the variance of vectors

Tags: variance, matrix

I have a vector of size `nxp` as follows

```
   V2    V3   V4    V5
 1.11 2.569 3.58 0.760
 1.19 2.928 3.75 0.821
 1.09 2.865 3.93 0.928
 1.25 3.844 3.94 1.009
 1.11 3.027 3.60 0.766
 1.08 2.336 3.51 0.726
 1.11 3.211 3.98 1.209
 1.16 3.037 3.62 0.750



    tmp <- structure(list(V2 = c(1.11, 1.19, 1.09, 1.25, 1.11, 1.08, 1.11, 
    1.16), V3 = c(2.569, 2.928, 2.865, 3.844, 3.027, 2.336, 3.211, 
    3.037), V4 = c(3.58, 3.75, 3.93, 3.94, 3.6, 3.51, 3.98, 3.62), 
    V5 = c(0.76, 0.821, 0.928, 1.009, 0.766, 0.726, 1.209, 0.75
    )), .Names = c("V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, 
    8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I know that the `var` function will provide the variance between `V2, V3,` etc..   `var(tmp)`

```
          V2         V3          V4          V5
V2 0.003392857 0.02027179 0.003739286 0.001778929
V3 0.020271786 0.20069070 0.058043036 0.045789554
V4 0.003739286 0.05804304 0.035183929 0.028483036
V5 0.001778929 0.04578955 0.028483036 0.028292696
```

How do I calculate these variance values manually using matrix algebra method. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to see a text that uses matrix algebra with statistics, look at the text by Shayle Searle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want [Sample mean and covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance)

$$
Q = \frac{1}{N-1}(M - 1_N\bar{x})^T (M-1_N\bar{x})
$$

```
covmat <- function(mat){
  M <- t(t(mat) - apply(mat,2,mean))
  N <- nrow(mat)
  Q <- 1/(N-1) * t(M) %*% M
  return(Q)
}

covmat(as.matrix(tmp))
```

Comment: this makes sense.